# Is there a way to check a field's accessibility through API

Tags: metadata, workbench

The standard field Email on CampaignMember object is not available through API, for which we use the workaround of having another custom field so that its accessible through API.

Is there any way to check from salesforce UI/ workbench for a fields accessibility through API? Something like, creatable, updateable that workbench shows on object fields..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't see the access information in the UI (I think) for fields (you can see for Custom Objects). You can, however, get Salesforce to describe an object's metadata for you, so you can see what you can retrieve from that specific object.

> Field Level Security can affect which objects & fields are available
>   in the API. The describe resources in the REST API will detail which
>   sobjects & the fields within them are available to the calling user.
>   e.g. see /services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Account/describe

From [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sRDIAY).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want this functionality through the workbench, you can write a `REST` service for it.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FieldAccess/*')
global class RESTPOC
{
    @HttpGet
    global static Boolean getIsAccessible()
    {
        String sObjectType = RestContext.request.params.get('sObject');
        String field = RestContext.request.params.get('field');

        SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
        if (schemaType == null) return false;

        SObjectField schemaField = schemaType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(field);
        if (schemaField == null) return false;

        return schemaField.getDescribe().isAccessible();
    }
}
```

Then you would use the `REST Explorer` to visit:

```
/services/apexrest/FieldAccess?sObject=CampaignMember&field=Email
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, An easy and quick way to check access once we've the rest service.

Comment: This can be achieved in multiple ways. To make describe call from workbench rest explorer is the out-of-box available one, which I marked as answer. Your post answers my question, and use cases are more versatile. Like from my inhouse application, I can check FLS by calling this. I liked it, so thought of mentioning it to you while accepting easier UI approach for the sake of others who face same problem. Sorry for confusion. Thanks for taking time to post the rest solution!

Comment: @Anusha Gotcha. Your first comment just seemed to imply you might have taken this approach. Glad you got it working.